# Will a transaction know about changes done in other transactions

Tags: postgresql, transactions

Lets say I have a table(Table1) with a Value field that has value=0.

Then two users(USER1 and USER2) run the transaction below concurrently

```
BEGIN
  UPDATE Table1 SET Value=Value+1; 
  UPDATE Table1 SET StatusField='Y' WHERE Value=2; 
COMMIT;
```

If the command is executed in the following order

USER1 starts transaction

USER2 start transaction

USER1 ends transaction;

USER2 ends transaction;

Will statusfield be set to Y?

NB! This is not a real life example, you should probably never want to use code like this, but I'm only trying to understand how transactions work. In other words what I want to know is, if two transactions starts at the same time and one of them finishes will the transaction already started know about the changes made by the first transaction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the isolation level chosen.

As soon as the default isolation level is `Read Committed` and you haven't changed it - the answer is "yes, it will be visible by the other transaction".

> `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, `SELECT FOR UPDATE`, and `SELECT FOR SHARE` commands behave the same as `SELECT` in terms of searching for target rows: they will only find target rows that were committed as of the command start time. However, such a target row might have already been updated (or deleted or locked) by another concurrent transaction by the time it is found. In this case, the would-be updater will wait for the first updating transaction to commit or roll back (if it is still in progress). If the first updater rolls back, then its effects are negated and the second updater can proceed with updating the originally found row.

The other isolation levels behaviour:

- `Read uncommitted` would behave the same;
- `Repeatable read` and `Serializable` would fail (in case the first transaction was committed successfully).

More at: [13.2.1. Read Committed Isolation Level](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/transaction-iso.html#XACT-READ-COMMITTED)